# Unable to Update label Outside Update Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have spent lot of time to investigate how to update label outside Update panel. And finally found something but it does not update label. It works fine if we refresh the page. Please let me know error in code or any new way of doing this. Please find my code below. I think need add some more code for script manager Or dataItem()
    Thank you guys for reply!
    Code behind file

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

using System.Web;

using System.Web.UI;

using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class scriptMgr : System.Web.UI.Page

{

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

protected void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

if (ScriptManager1.IsInAsyncPostBack)
{

ScriptManager1.RegisterDataItem(Label3, "Hi");
}
}

}
}



Aspx page

 <div>

<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="krwelkr"></asp:Label>

        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">

        </asp:ScriptManager>

        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

enter code here

        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoading(PageLoadingHandler);

        function PageLoadingHandler(sender, args) {

            var dataItems = args.get_dataItems();
            if ($get('Label3') != null)
                $get('Label3').innerHTML = dataItems['Label3'];

        }
    </script>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>

        </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer" EventName="Tick" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>


    </div>
```

Comment: leave those update panels and use jQuery + Ajax

Comment: add a hidden field in the update pannel and onload of the content in the update pannel use javascript to read the hiddenfield and then update ur label

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1a8bd63b-46e2-451a-ab6a-24e0de6774f8/update-label-outside-update-panel?forum=aspdotnetajax

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the ***[pageLoaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397523.ASPX)*** event of the `PageRequestManager`.

The ***[pageLoading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383832.ASPX)*** event is raised before any content on the page is updated. So your changes made in `pageLoading` event  will be lost if you also make changes to label's content anywhere else.

Therefore, when using the `pageLoaded` event which is raised after all content on the page is refreshed as a result of either a synchronous or an asynchronous postback, chnages made inside this event will overwrite all changes made anywhere else and will be the final.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(PageLoadedHandler)

        function PageLoadedHandler(sender, args) {

            var dataItems = args.get_dataItems();
            if ($get('Label3') != null)
               // set Label3 to your actual values. You can test/debug by adding
               // any test value
                $get('Label3').innerHTML = "TTTTestingggg";


        }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the register script in code behind event,

```
protected void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (ScriptManager1.IsInAsyncPostBack)
    {
      //ScriptManager1.RegisterDataItem(Label3, "Hi");
       ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "setLabelOrAnyName", "jQuery(function($) { $('#Label3').text('Whatever')});", true);
    }
 }
```

This should work.

Incase if you are not using `jQuery` library replace code with `simple javascript`.