# UpdatePanel with PostBackTrigger does not update the Label outside it and carry on after postbacks

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, postback, ispostback

I have an **update panel** with `postbacktriggers` and the label that I plan to update is in the **navbar**, which is **not included in the UpdatePanel where the triggers are located**. Below is the structure of that code:

```
<asp:Label ID="totalScorecardsLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnGenerateScorecard" />
                        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="exportPDFbtn" />
                        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="generateNewBtn" />
                    </Triggers>
                    <ContentTemplate>
                             divs.. etc
                    </ContentTemplate>
    </UpdatePanel>
```

On the other hand, I have a **click event** for `exportPDFbtn` that adds entries to a list, therefore incrementing the list size.

```
int totalScorecards = loadTest1.Count + loadTest2.Count + loadTest3.Count + loadTest4.Count;
totalScorecardsLabel.Text = totalScorecards.ToString();
```

The `totalScorecards` **Label** is **outside the UpdatePanel.** I've set it to `0` on `Page_Load if (!IsPostBack)`.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                   init();//initialize all lists etc
                   int totalScorecards = 0;
                   totalScorecardsLabel.Text = totalScorecards.ToString();
    }
}
```

After clicking the `exportPDFbtn`, I expect a **increment change** in the **label**. After that I plan to click the `generateNewScorecardbtn`, and expect the **totalScorecards** number to **carry on postbacks**.

But the problem is that the label is still on `0` even though elements are **successfully added** to the lists in the `exportPDF` **clickEvent** (used **breakpoints** to discover if it really adds to the lists). I also use `Server.Transfer("Scorecards.aspx")` for the `generateNewScorecardbtn`.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it into another Update Pannel and use Update() method 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.update(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Is the constructor required? What does `ViewState["LastUpdate"] = value;` do? Could you provide a snippet of your code idea?

Comment: ViewState["LastUpdate"]=value is used here to update the panel every five seconds here , i dont think you need that code. You just need to invoke UpdatePanel.Update() method

Answer (score 0):

It wont work if its outside the panel.
You need to put label in a separate update panel and it will work then.

Comment: I only have to put it inside another update panel? What else?

Comment: How about the UpdateMode property?

Comment: keep the UpdateMode property 'conditional'

Comment: It is not working. Just like the question in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18778623/unable-to-update-label-outside-update-panel)

Comment: remove the  'UpdateMode' property from your update panel with triggers.
but keep it 'conditional' on the new panel added.
hope it'll work

Comment: I've tried that one also but still no luck. The label is still `0` despite the postbacks.

Comment: In that case you should use jquey+ajax to assign value to label after your calculations..
or use a hidden field in your update panel (old one) and then on your button event assign label the value of hidden field.

Comment: I think there is a pageLoad issue, my lists would only increment once the clickevent has been called. After the next postback (Generate New Scorecard) button, it goes to the empty form page. Once I generate a new card and then export, the list increment from 0 to 1 again.

Comment: then you should use hidden field in your panel.Hidden field doesn't reset on postbacks

Comment: Are there any other solutions so that my globally declared lists won't keep on going back to having no elements after postbacks? I am also storing the score results of each card generated..